# Applying conditional rendering to all instances of a specific rendering

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

How can I apply a conditional rendering rule to all instances of a specific rendering (in an MVC application, if that's relevant)?

Based on the docs I have found, there should be a "Personalization" section but it doesn't appear in the Rendering's properties even though I've enabled it in "Application Options".

I've read that *global* conditional rendering rules aren't supported by MVC, but I assumed that meant that rules couldn't be applied to ALL renderings, not just all renderings of a specific type.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would also take a look at the following pipeline in [JetBrains DotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/)

```
<insertRenderings>
  <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.InsertRenderings.Processors.EvaluateConditions, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
</insertRenderings>
```

I would probably look to override the `GetGlobalRules` method to perform your custom logic, maybe load a custom set of conditions from Sitecore and add them to the `ruleList` so they also get evaluated.

Comment: Realistically, I think this tactic will work best for my requirements

Answer (score 3):

*"**Sitecore MVC solutions do not support global conditional rendering rules**, which is a form of conditional rendering that applies the same set of rules to all presentation components. You can apply conditional rendering rules for individual presentation components, but you cannot define conditional rendering rules that apply to all presentation components as you can with Web Forms solutions."* [Source: John West](http://www.sitecore.net/sverige/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2013/01/Conditional-Rendering-in-MVC-Solutions-That-Use-the-Sitecore-ASPNET-CMS.aspx)

So you need to use a different tactic:

If I understand this correctly, the conditional rendering rules are configured on item level. So that means that a *global* rule would have to be set on every item.

You can automate this by using template inheritance and `Standard Values`:

- Create a base template with standard values.
- Configure the rendering in the presentation details of the standard values item (this is where you setup the conditional rendering rules).
- Let all the templates that need this conditional rendering rule inherit from the base template.
- The presentation details on the standard values will also be inherited.

The only tricky thing with this solution is that you should setup all your templates and standard values before you create the items. *In theory this shouldn't matter*, but I've experienced some weird symptoms where inheritance of standard values presentation details would not work properly if you change them after the items have been created.

Comment: Global rules are available according to SitecoreJohn but I haven't used them personally... last paragraph http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2010/11/Sitecore-Rules-Engine-and-Conditional-Rendering.aspx

Comment: I am stack in the step two "Configure the rendering in the presentation details of the standard values item (this is where you setup the conditional rendering rules)." I only have Persona Visitor is human checkbox in the Personalization field. Can you give a detailed steps as in where I would create the conditional rendering rules?